# Query too intensive for server to execute on 5000 records

Tags: mysql

I have a query that builds a row of Sale information based on the Sale, Sale Items and Staff member involved. It works fine on my development server with 10-20 Sales, but when running on the end server with 5,000+ sales, it grinds the whole system to a halt.

```
SELECT Sales.SaleID,
Sales.StaffID,
Sales.CustomerID,
Sales.Timestamp,
Sales.Refunded,
Sales.PaymentType,
Staff.Forename AS staffForename,
Staff.Surname AS staffSurname,
itemList, sumOfCost,
sumOfPrice,
a.sumOfPrice - a.sumOfCost AS sumOfProfit

FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Staff ON Sales.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT SaleID,
              GROUP_CONCAT(Quantity, ' x ', Name) itemList,
              SUM(Cost*Quantity) sumOfCost, SUM(Price*Quantity) sumOfPrice
              FROM SaleItems GROUP BY SaleID
          ) a
ON a.SaleID = Sales.SaleID

WHERE Sales.Deleted = '0'
AND Sales.ShopID = '0'
ORDER BY Sales.Timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,15
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! The last attempt at this query took 65 seconds...

Comment: avoid subqueries. I know that now much useful but i would like to start with it.

Comment: the tables that you use... are indexed?

Comment: @BhavikShah I would love to avoid using sub-queries, but I'm afraid I don't yet know how to conver the above query to a sub-query!

Comment: @avi No they are not sadly, with them being looked at based on several different variables, how effective would doing so be?

Comment: very! is a must actually... try that and then run your query

Comment: @avi Just checked and it turns out I have a BTREE index on both SaleID in Sales and SaleItemID in SaleItems

Comment: i see that you have a join with the Staff table... ca you index that table too? actualy all the tables that are participating in a query with join should be indexed for better performance. I had once a table with only 3 rows that was not indexed... and i used it in a join with a table with 2 milion records... and the query lasted like at least 30 seconds... after index on that table with 3 records... the query was instant

Comment: @avi Same again, the Staff table is indexed on StaffID :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I just going crazy, or is this exactly what I need?

```
SELECT Sales.SaleID,
Sales.StaffID, 
Sales.CustomerID, 
Sales.Timestamp, 
Sales.Refunded, 
Sales.PaymentType, 
Staff.Forename AS staffForename, 
Staff.Surname AS staffSurname, 
GROUP_CONCAT(SaleItems.Name) AS ItemList, 
SUM(Cost) AS sumOfCost, 
SUM(Price) AS sumOfCost, 
SUM(Price) - SUM(Cost) AS sumOfProfit 
FROM Sales 
JOIN Staff ON Sales.StaffID = Staff.StaffID 
JOIN SaleItems ON Sales.SaleID = SaleItems.SaleID 
WHERE Sales.Deleted = '0' 
AND Sales.ShopID = '0' 
GROUP BY SaleItems.SaleID 
ORDER BY Sales.Timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

It appears to give the right results, but seems REMARKEBLY less convoluted, and thus a little confusing that I didn't see it before?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have a sub-query (in my opinion).  To me, a sub-query is one that relies on a record from another table in the query and is processed for each row.  Your version is just a full query run once, getting a full result set, then having that as basis for the join to your other tables.

Next, all your tables should have the obvious indexes as stated in comments by others such as to handle all your JOIN conditions (join to staff ID, Sales ID, etc).  However, you should ALSO have an index to help optimize your CRITERIA... In this case, I would have an index on

```
(Deleted, ShopID, SaleID )
```

The reason to include your "SaleID" column is to be used optimizing your GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.  It appears you only want the most recent 15 sales.  Since a timestamp would be directly associated with a sale transaction, it would imply that SaleID # 1 had a timestamp before SaleID #2, and so on for Sale ID #3, #4, #5 respectively.  That said, I would just have the order by the Sale ID DESCENDING which accomplishes the same result.

Now, for your query.  What you originally had was a pre-query that aggregated ALL SALES, EVERY ITEM for their respective cost and price.  That is probably what is killing your performance.  You are only then throwing away all the records that do not qualify your outermost WHERE criteria.

So now you know where I'm coming from, I would do the following.  My "PreQuery" is nothing but a select from the sales table to get the most recent 15 sales of your criteria of deleted and shop ID, but ordered by the sale ID descending (basically same thing as timestamp per above example)... And limiting that to 15.  THEN, finish your join and group by so you are only aggregating those line items associated with 15 sales, not the entire database of sales.  Since the "PreQuery" is already pre-ordered with newest up front, we don't have to re-reorder the outer result set.

I DO need to keep the group-by at the outer level because you could have 10 line items for a single sale ID and want to show only the final grand total entry for the sale.

```
    SELECT 
          S.SaleID,
          S.StaffID,
          S.CustomerID,
          S.Timestamp,
          S.Refunded,
          S.PaymentType,
          Staff.Forename AS staffForename,
          Staff.Surname AS staffSurname,
          GROUP_CONCAT(SI.Quantity, ' x ', SI.Name) itemList,
          SUM(SI.Cost*SI.Quantity) sumOfCost, 
          SUM(SI.Price*SI.Quantity) sumOfPrice,
          SUM(SI.Price*SI.Quantity) - SUM(SI.Cost*SI.Quantity) AS sumOfProfit
       FROM 
          ( select Sales.SaleID
               FROM Sales
               WHERE Sales.Deleted = '0'
                  AND Sales.ShopID = '0'
               ORDER BY 
                  Sales.SaleID DESC 
               LIMIT 
                  0,15 ) PreQuery
             JOIN Sales S
                on PreQuery.SaleID = S.SaleID
                JOIN SaleItems SI
                   ON Sales.SaleID = SI.SaleID
                JOIN Staff 
                   ON S.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
   group by
      S.SaleID
```